# Converting 24 to 16 bit audio using SSE/simd instructions

Tags: audio, simd, sse2, quantization, sse3

I wonder if there is any fast method to do a 24 bit to 16 bit quantization on an array of audio samples (using intrinsics or asm).

Source format is signed 24 le.

Update :
Managed to get the conversion done like described :

```
static void __cdecl Convert24bitToStereo16_SSE2(uint8_t* src, uint8_t* dst, int len)
{
    __m128i shuffleMask = _mm_setr_epi8(-1,0,1,2,-1,3,4,5,-1,6,7,8,-1,9,10,11);             

    __asm 
  {    
        mov        eax, [src]   // src          
        mov        edi, [dst]   // dst
        mov        ecx, [len]   // len

        movdqu     xmm0,xmmword ptr [shuffleMask]           

      convertloop:
        movdqu     xmm1, [eax]              // read 4 samples           
        lea        eax,  [eax + 12]         // inc pointer                      
        pshufb     xmm1,xmm0                // shuffle using mask
        psrldq     xmm1, 2                  // shift right

        movdqu     xmm2, [eax]              // read next 4 samples          
        lea        eax,  [eax + 12]         // inc pointer                      
        pshufb     xmm2, xmm0               // shuffle
        psrldq     xmm2, 2                  // shift right
        packusdw   xmm1, xmm2               // pack upper and lower samples

        movdqu     [edi], xmm1              // write 8 samples
        lea        edi, [edi + 16]
        sub        ecx, 24
        jg         convertloop
  }
}
```

Now for the dithering - how to avoid quantization effects ?

Any hint is welcome. Thx

Comment: 24 to 16 bits is pretty straightforward - you load three 128 bit values, then you shuffle (`_mm_shuffle_epi8`) bytes to drop each third byte, and eventually store two 128 bit values as the result. Slightly more complicated if you need accurate rounding.

Comment: @RomanR. I don't think that is going to take care of the dithering problem.

Comment: What kind of dithering do you want to apply ?

Answer (score 3):

Your final code looks weird.  Why shuffle and then do a bytewise shift of the entire register?  Instead, set up you shuffle control mask to put things in the right place to start with.

Also, `packusdw` doesn't convert full-range 32bit to full-range 16bit.  It saturates (to 0xffff) any 32bit element greater than 2^16-1.  So you have to right-shift the data yourself, to go from 24bit full range to 16bit full range.  (In audio, the conversion from 16 to 24 bits is done by adding 8 zero bits as least-signifcant bits, not most-significant.)

Anyway, the implication of this is that we want to pack the high 16b of every 24bits of input back-to-back.  We can just do this with a shuffle.

```
//__m128i shuffleMask = _mm_setr_epi8(-1,0,1,2,-1,3,4,5,-1,6,7,8,-1,9,10,11);
// setr takes its args in reverse order, so right-shift by 2 bytes -> move the first 2 args
//__m128i shiftedMask = _mm_setr_epi8(1,2,-1,3,4,5,-1,6,7,8,-1,9,10,11,-1,-1);

// could get 10B, but packing that into the output would be slower
__m128i mask_lo = _mm_setr_epi8( 1,2,  4,5,   7,8,   10,11,
                                -1,-1, -1,-1, -1,-1, -1,-1);
//    __m128i mask_hi = _mm_setr_epi8(-1,-1, -1,-1, -1,-1, -1,-1,
//                                     1,2,  4,5,   7,8,   10,11);
//  generate this from mask_lo instead of using more storage space  

  ... pointer setup
  movdqu     xmm3, xmmword ptr [mask_lo]
  pshufd     xmm4, xmm3, 0x4E  // swap high/low halves

  convertloop:
    movdqu     xmm0, [eax]              // read 4 samples
    pshufb     xmm0, xmm3               // low 8B = 24->16 of first 12B, high8 = 0
    movdqu     xmm1, [eax + 12]         // read next 4 samples
    pshufb     xmm1, xmm4               // high 8B = 2nd chunk of audio, low8 = 0
    por        xmm1, xmm0               // merge the two halves

    movdqu     [edi], xmm1              // write 8 samples
    add        eax, 24
    lea        edi, [edi + 16]
    sub        ecx, 24
    jg         convertloop
```

Also, be careful about reading past the end of the array.  Each `movdqu` reads 16B, but you only use the first 12.

I could have used the same mask twice, and used `PUNPCKLQDQ` to put the high 8B into the top half of the reg holding the low 8B.  However, `punpck` instructions compete for the same port as `pshufb`.  (ports 1, 5 on Nehalem/Sandybridge/IvyBridge, port 5 only on Haswell.)  `por` can run on any of ports 0,1,5, even on Haswell, so it doesn't create a port5 bottleneck problem.

Loop overhead is too high without unrolling to saturate port5 even on Haswell, but it's close.  (9 fused-domain uops, 2 of them requiring port5.  There's no loop-carried dependency, and enough of the uops are loads/stores that 4uops per cycle should be possible.)  Unrolling by 2 or 3 should do the trick.  Nehalem/Sandybridge/Ivybridge won't bottleneck on execution ports, since they can shuffle on two ports.  Core2 takes 4 uops for `PSHUFB`, and can only sustain 1 per 2 cycles, but it's still the fastest way to do this data movement.  Penryn (aka wolfdale) should be fast for this too, but I haven't looked at details.  Decoder throughput will be an issue on pre-Nehalem, though.

So if everything's in L1 cache, we can generate 16B of 16b audio per 2 cycles.  (Or less, with some unrolling, on pre-Haswell.)

AMD CPUs (e.g. Steamroller) also have `pshufb` on the same port as `punpck`, while booleans can run on either of the other 2 vector ports, so it's the same situation.  Shuffles are higher latency than on Intel, but throughput is still 1 per cycle.

If you want proper rounding instead of truncation, add something like 2^7 to the samples before truncation.  (Probably requiring some sign-adjustment.)  If you want dithering, you need something even more complex, and should google that up, or look for a library implementation.  Audacity is open source, so you could look at how they do it.